# Is it possible to customize apex page messages in visualforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagemessages

I basically want to change the title of the box showing the mes[image]

Is it possible in an official way to change those titles? Or do I have to write custom html to accomplish that? I didn't find relevant information on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `<apex:pageMessages>` it is not possible. The component is presented using "Salesforce styling", and it does not expose a "title" attribute, as stated in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm).

`<apex:pageMessage>`, however, can have its "title" ([the title text for the message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessage.htm)) modified.